# Simple linear equation question

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry, school was like a long time ago for me, so this is really hard nowadays:

Lets say you have this loan/fee table:

```
Loan     Fee

$100 --> $15   

$300 --> $25  

$500 --> $35
```

The fee is made up of a base rate (e.g. 10 dollars) and a variable amount (e.g. 5 dollars per 100). Since there are two unknown variables, is there a way to solve this without using trial and error?

E.g. The answer that solves the above looks like this:

```
($10 + $5 per $100)
```

Also, not sure if this formula changes when the first hundred is excluded from the variable rate. E.g. Using same table as above:

```
Loan     Fee

$100 --> $10   **($10 + $0 per $100)**

$300 --> $20   ($10 + $5 per $100)

$500 --> $30   ($10 + $10 per $100)
```

I think this can be solved with linear equation but not sure how to write or solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a system of equations using the given information and solve it to get the base rate and the variable rate:

$b=$ base

$x=$ variable rate

$$
  \begin{align}
     b+100x &=15 \\
     b+300x &=25     \\
     b+500x &=35  
  \end{align} 
$$
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c} 
  1 & 100 & 15 \\
  1 & 300 & 25 \\
  1 & 500 & 35 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$
$
\begin{matrix}
\\
R_2-R_1\\
R_3-R_1\\
\end{matrix}
$
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c} 
  1 & 100 & 15 \\
  0 & 200 & 10 \\
  0 & 400 & 20 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$
$
\begin{matrix}
2R_1-R_2\\
\\
R_3-2R_2\\
\end{matrix}
$
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c} 
  2 & 0 & 20 \\
  0 & 200 & 10 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$
$
\begin{matrix}
R_1\div2\\
\\
R_2\div200\\
\end{matrix}
$
$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|c} 
  1 & 0 & 10 \\
  0 & 1 & \frac 1{20} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$
$
\begin{matrix}
b=10\\
x=\frac1{20}\\
\\
\end{matrix}
$

So you get a solution to this system of equations with the base being $10$ and the variable rate is equal to $\frac 1{20}$ (i.e 5 for everyone 100). You really only needed two of the equations to solve for the variables, but the fact that there is a zero row in the bottom just confirms that all three equations are consistent.